# C#, WinForm: cannot set designer-created-control with code-created control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, designer

I've been playing with Windows Form Application for a half year, and now I found a very wired thing: The control created in Form Designer cannot be set with another instance in code.

Here is what I've done:

I create a Windows Form Application, the main form is Form1 class. And I drag a GroupBox control to Form1, then I add this code in Form_Load event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
        gb.Text = "gb in code";
        groupBox1 = gb;
        //groupBox1.Text = "set in code";
    }
```

Normally, I thought it will give instance groupBox1 the new value of 'gb', which is another instance of GroupBox class, the the Text property is "gb in code". However, when I press F5, compile and run, the groupBox1 Text is still "groupBox1". And even if I uncomment the last line, the groupBox1 Text is not changed to "set in code".

I feel it's so wired. Is it because I created the groupBox1 instance in Form Designer? So I cannot revalue it in another partial of class?

I kinda need to revalue the control created in Form Designer, for my user controls.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks guys :)

--------------------EDIT---------------------

What I want to achieve is: I have two user controls: UC1 and UC2, and Now I'm creating another user control UC3, which contains UC1 and UC2. When I initiate UC3, I want to pass the instance of UC1 and UC2 to UC3, otherwise I have to pass all the property values of UC1 and UC2 to UC3. And I kinda need to use Designer for UC3, to re-size UC1 and UC2.

So in UC3, I drag my UC1 and UC2 to UC3 Designer, and I make a public property point to UC1 and UC2, like:

```
    public UserControl param_UC1
    {
        get
        {
            return UC1;
        }
        set
        {
            UC1 = value;
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, the UC1 is not set by param_UC1. Now I think I should not use designer, just add UC1 during the Load event.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Did you use "partial" on both classes? --> "public partial class Foo"

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is completely incorrect.

What you're doing here.. is creating a reference to an in-memory `GroupBox` instance. Then you're pointing your current reference at this new instance. That means both references are pointing at your in-memory `GroupBox`.. your `GroupBox` on your form is now completely unreferenced.

If you need to set properties on the control.. do so through the initial reference. Currently you're changing properties of your in-memory `GroupBox`. Your thinking here is completely wrong.. maybe you would benefit from telling us what you're trying to achieve so that we can help you achieve that goal.

Comment: Hi Simon, I added something to my question, please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should just use a framework like Automapper. It will copy everything for you. It will require minimal setup too .. since you're copying to exactly the same objects.